# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Application Restart - Memory Usage

Tags: iis, asp.net, memory-usage

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 (NopCommerce 4.0) application on IIS v.1607

When my process arrives at (approximately) 1300MB of memory, the web site stops responding, and after some minutes the application restarts automatically.

(there is also a kepp alive task)

Application is on dedicated hosting with more free memory.

Can I change these parameters on IIS?
thanks